# Демон не выводит изображения на экран

Tags: python, консоль, cron

делаю автозапуск программы при включении (Jetson nano). Написал программку, которая демонстрирует слйд шоу время от времени, через feh. Запускается и работает, через терминал отлично. Но если попытаться запустить ее через `crontab @reboot` не работает. Но я посмотрел процессы и нашел там мою программу.Значит он все таки запустилась. Как заставить этого демона выводить изображение на экран?
Зарнее, спасибо

Comment: крон к пользовательской сессии никак не привязан. у вас может быть залогинено пять чел. кому он показывать должен?

Comment: Как можно жестко зафиксировать показ одному и тому же пользователю всегда ?